# Differentiating b/w memory bound and compute bound CUDA kernels

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu

I am trying to write a static analyzer for differentiating between data intensive and computation intensive CUDA kernels. As much as I have researched on this topic, there is not much literature present on it. One of the ways to accomplish this is to calculate the CGMA ratio of the kernel. If it is 'too high', then it might be compute intensive, otherwise, memory intensive.

The problem with the above method is that I can't seem to decide upon a threshold value for the ratio. That is, above what value should it be classified as compute intensive. One way is to use the ratio of CUDA cores and load/store units as threshold. What does SO think?

I came across this paper in which they are calculating a parameter called 'memory intensity'. First, they calculate a parameter called the activity factor, which is then used to calculate memory intensity. Please find the paper [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oP2_EEQliPTjvClDRy8wdpojoTEQ_vX-/view?usp=sharing). You can find memory intensity on page no: 6.

Does there exist any better approach? I am kind-of stuck in my research due to this, and desperately need help.

Comment: I think you're stuck because this is not a black-and-white distinction. Different parts of a kernel will be bottlenecked on different things, down to a single instruction and up to the entire kernel. You can discuss things like "80% of the time is spent on memory bottlenecks", or "greater than 50% of this kernel is bottlenecked on compute", but there is no single boolean category that captures this information.

Comment: How good does the CGMA ratio capture it?

Comment: My point is there is no "it". Maybe the first half of the kernel is totally memory-bound and the latter half is totally compute bound. This would show up as "50% CGMA" - whether or not this is useful information is subjective. Or imagine a kernel is 80% memory-bound, so we summarize this as "this kernel is memory bound", without attaching any percentage or location. Whether or not this is useful is again dependent on what you need the information for.

Comment: You make a point. Looks like I need to abandon this approach.

Comment: @GManNickG Please add you comment as an answer.

Comment: I voted to close as being too opinion-based, so I don't think me answering is appropriate. :) Feel free to write your own conclusions as an answer or maybe someone who feels there is a more objective answer can chime in.

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks.

Comment: I also believe there is no simple or generally agreed upon answer.  For one viewpoint, consider slides 6-19  [here](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/sc_2010/CUDA_Tutorial/SC10_Analysis_Driven_Optimization.pdf)